# Confused about static dictionary in a type, in F#

Tags: f#

With this type:

```
type A =
    {
        S: string
    }

    static member private l = Dictionary<string, A>()
    static member add s = A.l.[s] <- { S=s }
    static member list () = l.Values
```

if I do:

```
A.add "hello"
A.add "world"
```

I'd expect A.list() to return something since the dictionary is static, but it returns an empty list. Why is that?

To clarify what I'm trying to do: I'd like to have the ability to register the objects of type A into a static dictionary that is attached to the type itself as it would make the object repository 'self contained' in the type, in a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `l` is not a *field*, but a *property* with a *getter*.

A "property", contrary to appearances, is not a memory cell with some value in it. A "property" is a pair of get+set functions. Just functions, that's all. No memory cell.

So what you made yourself is a property with a getter (without a setter), and all that getter does is create a new `Dictionary` and return it.

This means, every time you access `A.l`, you get yourself a new, fresh dictionary. Because `l` is a function, not a memory cell.

Now, in order to make a memory cell (aka "field"), one would ordinarily use `static member val`, like so:

```
static member val private l = Dictionary<string, A>()
```

Unfortunately, in this particular case this doesn't work, because static fields are not permitted on F# records and unions. They work fine on actual classes, but not on F# types.

So instead what I would recommend is to put those functions in a *module* rather than making them static methods:

```
type A = { S: string }

module A =
  let private l = Dictionary<string, A>()
  let add s = l.[s] <- { S=s }
  let list () = l.Values
```

(and just in general: try to use fewer classes and more modules and functions; they're more idiomatic in F# and lead to fewer problems in general)

Now this works as expected:

```
> A.add "hello";;
val it : unit = ()

> A.add "world";;
val it : unit = ()

> A.list();;
val it : Dictionary`2.ValueCollection<string,A> =
  seq [{ S = "hello" }; { S = "world" }]
```

Comment: I've opened another question to seek some clarification on your last advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892521/types-vs-modules-in-f