# Types vs. Modules in F#

Tags: f#

The answer on [Confused about static dictionary in a type, in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66880212/confused-about-static-dictionary-in-a-type-in-f) finished with one advice: `and just in general: try to use fewer classes and more modules and functions; they're more idiomatic in F# and lead to fewer problems in general`

Which is a great point, but my 30 years of OO just don't want to give up classes just yet (although I was fighting against C++ like crazy when we moved away from C...)

so let's take a practical real world object:

```
type Currency =
    {
        Ticker: string
        Symbol: char
    }

and MarginBracket =
    {
        MinSize:           decimal
        MaxSize:           decimal
        Leverage:          int
        InitialMargin:     decimal
        MaintenanceMargin: decimal
    }

and Instrument =
    {
        Ticker:             string
        QuantityTickSize:   int
        PriceTickSize:      int
        BaseCurrency:       Currency
        QuoteCurrency:      Currency
        MinQuantity:        decimal
        MaxQuantity:        decimal
        MaxPriceMultiplier: decimal
        MinPriceMultiplier: decimal
        MarginBrackets:     MarginBracket array
    }

    // formatting
    static member private formatValueNoSign (precision: int) (value: decimal) =
        let zeros = String.replicate precision "0"
        String.Format($"{{0:#.%s{zeros}}}", value)

    static member private formatValueSign (precision: int) (value: decimal) =
        let zeros = String.replicate precision "0"
        String.Format($"{{0:+#.%s{zeros};-#.%s{zeros}; 0.%s{zeros}}}", value)


    member this.BaseSymbol  = this.BaseCurrency.Symbol
    member this.QuoteSymbol = this.QuoteCurrency.Symbol

    member this.QuantityToString    (quantity)          = $"{this.BaseSymbol}{Instrument.formatValueSign    this.QuantityTickSize quantity}"
    member this.PriceToString       (price)             = $"{this.QuoteSymbol}{Instrument.formatValueNoSign this.PriceTickSize price}"
    member this.SignedPriceToString (price)             = $"{this.QuoteSymbol}{Instrument.formatValueSign   this.PriceTickSize price}"
    member this.RoundQuantity       (quantity: decimal) = Math.Round (quantity, this.QuantityTickSize)
    member this.RoundPrice          (price : decimal)   = Math.Round (price, this.PriceTickSize)

    // price deviation allowed from instrument price
    member this.LowAllowedPriceDeviation (basePrice: decimal)  = this.MinPriceMultiplier * basePrice
    member this.HighAllowedPriceDeviation (basePrice: decimal) = this.MaxPriceMultiplier * basePrice


module Instrument =
    let private  allInstruments   = Dictionary<string, Instrument>()
    let list     ()               = allInstruments.Values
    let register (instrument)     = allInstruments.[instrument.Ticker] <- instrument
    let exists   (ticker: string) = allInstruments.ContainsKey (ticker.ToUpper())
    let find     (ticker: string) = allInstruments.[ticker.ToUpper()]
```

In this example, there is an *Instrument* object with its data and a few helper members and a module which acts as a repository when it's time to find an object by name (a trading ticker in this case, so they're known and formatted, it's not a random string)

I could move the helping member to the module, for example:

```
member this.LowAllowedPriceDeviation (basePrice: decimal)  = this.MinPriceMultiplier * basePrice
```

could become:

```
let lowAllowedPriceDeviation basePrice instrument = instrument.MinPriceMultiplier * basePrice
```

So the object would become simpler and could eventually be turned into a simple storage type without any augmentations.

But I am wondering what are the practical benefits (let's just consider readability, maintainability, etc)?

Also, I don't see how this could be re-structured to not be a class, short of having an 'internal' class in the module and doing all operations through that, but that would just be shifting it.

Comment: There is no need for the ´and´ keyword. It is bad practice to use that keyword when it's not needed, because you imply to the reader that there is a recursive dependency when in fact there isn't. That just overloads the reader needlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition about turning `LowAllowedPriceDeviation` to a module is correct: it could become a function with the `this` parameter moved to the end. That is an accepted pattern.

Same goes for all other methods on the `Instrument` type. And the two private static methods could be come private functions in the module. The exact same approach.

The question *"how this could be re-structured to not be a class"* confuses me a bit, because this is not actually a class. `Instrument` is a record, not a class. The fact that you gave it some instance and static methods doesn't make it a class.

And finally (though, technically, this part is opinion-based), regarding *"what are the practical benefits"* - the answer is "composability". Functions can compose in the way that methods can't.

For example, say you wanted a way to print multiple instruments:

```
let printAll toString = List.iter (printfn "%s" << toString)
```

See how it's parametrized with a `toString` function? That's because I'd like to use it for printing instruments in different ways. For example, I might print their prices:

```
printAll priceToString (list())
```

But if `PriceToString` is a method, I'd have to introduce an anonymous function:

```
printAll (fun i -> i.PriceToString) (list())
```

This looks just a little bit more involved than using a function, but in practice it gets very complicated fast. A bigger problem, however, is that this wouldn't even compile because type inference doesn't work on properties (because it can't). In order to get it to compile, you have to add a type annotation, making it even uglier:

```
printAll (fun (i: Instrument) -> i.PriceToString) (list())
```

That's just one example of function composability, there are many others. But I'd rather not write a whole blog post on this subject, it's already much longer than I'd like.